# How to build a List on-click ?MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having List of Questions where i am looping through HTML controls.
My view will be like:

```
@{int index = 0;}
@foreach (Models.Qualification qual in Model) 
{
    @qual.LeadQualifition;  //Here my question will sit
    <div class="radio-list radio-list-padding">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="serious" value="1" >                                  
                Negative 
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="serious" value="3" >                            
               Positive 
        </label>    
<input type="hidden" value="@qual.CriteriaId" />        // i have to pass this id                    
    </div>
    @(index++);
}
<input type="button" onclick="save()" />
```

Onclick i have to get the selected radio-buttons which are generated dynamically based on foreach.

I cant use the form post method.I should build a List on-click.Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: So u want to get list of selected radio buttons?

Comment: What did you try so far? What did you google for so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: why are you using plain HTMl control, use HTML extension of MVC i mean use HTML.RadioButtonFor(m=> Model.YOURPROPERTY)

Comment: @Aaron is right. If you really want to do this with `jQuery` alone, then that's fine. But you could just post a list of values directly to the controller if you just use the built in helpers. There are a lot of examples out there, most notably one from [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

Comment: ... there is no such thing as a list in javascript. If you want a C# list, you will need to post the data.

Comment: well i tried using html helpers but i cant find much difference in this scenario as i am not using any `html.beginform` or other methods to post list to controller . i been trying to construct a list later on click i post it via ajax call

Comment: Do it again and tell us if you also see a `hidden` input for every `radio`, having the same name. The `radio` will have `value="true"` and the `hidden` input will have `value="false"`. And that's you most important difference.

Comment: @AndreiV yes you are right . excuse my ignorance . i just forgot to post my important bit in my code . updated my code . cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a array and save checked checkboxes value in that array as shown :-

```
var arr=[];
$("input[name='serious']").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
  arr.push($(this).val());
}
});
```

**EDIT :-**

After questioner update in question i m adding some more code here :

You can store `CriteriaId` with every radio button(no need to have extra hidden field) as :

```
<input type="radio" name="serious" value="1" data-id="@qual.CriteriaId">
```

Now Jquery code will look like this :

```
 var arr=[];
 $("input[name='serious']").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
  arr.push($(this).val());
  arr.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
  }
 });
```

So in above array 0,2... index will have checkbox value and 1,3.. will have CriteriaId value,you can take a seperate array for CriteriaId also.

**EDIT :-**

If want to get hidden field value in Jquery then provide a unique id to hidden field like this :

```
<input type="hidden" value="@qual.CriteriaId" id="CriteriaId" />
```

and get its value in Jquery as :

```
var CriteriaId = $("#CriteriaId").val();
```

Comment: +1 though answer is correct, but it will lead to misunderstanding at server side what value to assign to whom as it is in array. I prefer to avoid such ways:)

Comment: A list of objects (key-value) would have been better. It could have then be deserialized as a `Dictionary<string, Boolean>` on the server.

Comment: @Aaron..well the questioner asked to make a list of values so i think above answer will work fine for this requirement

Comment: @Exception yes by the look i can say it will work fine but how to pass radio button values and with that criteriaid which is stored in hidden field with each radio button selection . updated my code. sorry for missing the line previously

Comment: @Exception  No , because if i have criteriaid binded to radio buttons i will have same id used which is but redundant. so i tought rather keeping for each radio button i done some hidden field stuff to pass my id .

Comment: @Exception things getting more clear now . thank you for summing u some wonderful stuff . just curious any guess how to pass criteriaId just in-case if it is stored in hidden field .